# Custom permission level to overpower "edit your own" items

Tags: permissions

I have created a SharePoint list for users requests. I have granted users "Contribute" permission level and set option "edit your own items". So that users can create requests and modify them later on (but only those created by them).

I have granted the team the Design permission level. So that the team can execute requests and then modify any item on SharePoint to reflect it. That's what I wanted.

However, the Design level allows to change the list itself and I'm not happy with it. I'm looking for a permission level which will allow to change all the items, but will not allow to change columns, say.

Can I construct such permission level? I tried a bit myself, but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom permission level from the 'Design' permission level:

1. Go to "Site Settings"
2. "Site Permissions" (under Users and Permissions section)
3. "Permission Levels" (in the ribbon)
4. Click on "Design" permission level
5. "Copy Permission Level" at the bottom-right
6. Now run through all the permissions and untick the ones that you don't want users to have
7. Specify the name for your custom permission level and "Create"

Comment: If you want to restrict users from modifying List Columns, 'Manage Lists' permission is the one that allows that :)

Comment: Dear Gintas, 
thank you for the answer. that's what I was doing indeed.
If I remove permission "Manage Lists" and grant this custom permission level to the team members, they also can't edit items not created by them.
This is my struggle. It seems there is no way to remove the rights to create columns, etc, but keep the rights to edit others items.